# Typical configuration file for test_changes gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The [test changes](https://github.com/gsmendoza/test_changes) gem looks useful and lightweight.  What would be an example `.test-changes.yml` file that would be useful for a typical rails application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the [test_changes](https://github.com/gsmendoza/test_changes) gem. Here's a snippet of the configuration file I'm using for our Rails/RSpec app:

```
rspec:
  finding_patterns:
    ^app/(.+)\.rb: spec/\1_spec.rb
    ^lib/(.+)\.rb: spec/lib/\1_spec.rb
    ^spec/(.+)_spec.rb: spec/\1_spec.rb
```

That's pretty much all you need to get started :)

`test_changes` is also useful for tying a module or support file to multiple tests. For example, we have something like this:

```
rspec:
  finding_patterns:
    ^app/concerns/mobile_site.rb:
    - spec/acceptance/sign_in_spec.rb
    - spec/acceptance/sign_up_spec.rb

    ^spec/factories/product_factory.rb:
    - spec/acceptance/orders_admin_spec.rb
    - spec/models/product_spec.rb
```

Hope that helps!